# How to declare the JSON+LD for a breadcrumb that has 2 items in the same position?

Tags: wordpress, blog, json-ld, breadcrumbs

Let us assume that one Blog allows both nested categories, and one post can have multiple categories as well.

A post named "best laravel practices" might have category "laravel" and category "php" assigned, both of them.

The breadcrumb in a WordPress site looks visually like below:

[image]

Can I use position 2 for both those items in the breadcrumb and end up with JSON-LD like below:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "name": "Blog",
      "item": "https://example.com/blog"
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "name": "Laravel",
      "item": "https://example.com/blog/category/laravel"
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "name": "Php",
      "item": "https://example.com/blog/category/php"
    }    
  ]
}
</script>
```

Please note above both PHP and Laravel have position 2.
Is that allowed, or every position should have only 1 item and be unique?

PS: Creating these breadcrumbs is a little complicated because sometimes they are nested with a hierarchy, parent-child categories, other times the post might have only multiple categories that are on top level.